# PHP repeat an HTML element without using loop

Tags: php, loops

This might be crazy, but I was thinking there might be a shorthand way to do this without using a loop on one php line... over-optimizing fun!

```
$stars = 4; // four out of ten stars
```

print stars with a loop

```
for($i=0;$i<$stars;$i++){
 echo "<i class='fi-star'></i>";
}
```

print without loop

```
<?=implode("",array_fill(0,$stars,"<i class='fi-star'></i>"))?>
```

is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can use `str_repeat`

Comment: *"over-optimizing fun!"* The simple for loop is probably faster than your *fancy* one-liner.

Comment: Any way you do this will probably involve a loop at some point in the code, potentially behind the scenes, so I don't know if this would be optimizing.

Comment: `"is there a simpler way?"` - Simpler than... *a loop*?  If you want to repeat an action until a condition is met, that's *exactly* what a loop is for.  You're likely saving nothing in optimization but costing time in obtuse code.  Even if you somehow manage to save a millisecond is processing time, it's going to require *a lot* of application volume to make up for all the development time spent creating and supporting "clever code".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`str_repeat`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) function.

In your case, you can use it like this:

```
echo str_repeat("<i class='fi-star'></i>", $stars);
```

Note that this won't make your code any more efficient. It is just a shorthand way to do the same as what you are doing with the for loop.